# How can I upload a folder in Github Codespaces?

Tags: file, github, github-pages, codespaces, github-codespaces

I don't often have access to Github desktop, which is the only way I've seen so far, and dragging a folder into "upload files" doesn't work either.

I've tried dragging a folder onto codespaces, too. Is using Github Desktop is the only way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.